# Api-Platform Foreign key is null on Relation

Tags: symfony-3.4, api-platform.com

link by a oneToMany and ManyToOne relation. I use normalization and denormalization on entity Commmande, is set correctly because it's working on all field . But the field commande,on PrestationsLaboratoire, use by foreign key is alway null.
I have tried to read many post, but any result.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"readCO"}},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"writeCO"}} 
 * })
 * 
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy="exact")
 * 
 * @var Commande clients
 */
 class Commande  {

     // les types de commandes
     const ROUTINE = "ROUTINE";
     const LABORATOIRE = "LABORATOIRE";
     const FOURNITURE = "FOURNITURE";
    // les status 
    const IS_ORDERED = "IS_ORDERED";
    const IS_VALIDATE = "IS_VALIDATE";
    const IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS";
    const IS_TERMINATED = "IS_TERMINATED";
    const IS_CANCELED = "IS_CANCELED";
    const ERROR_STATUS = "ERROR_SAISIE_STATUS"; 

/**
 * @var id
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var le commanditaire de la commande 
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=45)
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected  $commanditaire;


/**
 * @var date de la commande
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
* @Assert\DateTime(format="Y-m-d\TH:i:sP") 
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
*/
protected $date;



/**
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PrestationsLaboratoire",mappedBy="commande",cascade={"persist"},fetch="EAGER")
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 * @MaxDepth(2)
 * 
 */
protected  $prestalabos;


/**
 * @var les forunitures
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Fourniture")
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 * @MaxDepth(2)
 */
protected  $fournitures;


/**
 * @var les routines
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Routine", inversedBy="commande", cascade={"persist"},fetch="EAGER")
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 * @MaxDepth(2)
 */
protected  $routine;


/**
 * @var status de la commande : IS_ORDERED,IS_VALIDATED,IN_PROGRESS,IS_TERMINATED,IS_CANCELED
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=15)
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $status;

/**
 * @var ref de la comande pour le client
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=30)
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $refClient;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entreprise",inversedBy="commandes",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $entreprise;


public function __construct() {

    $this->prestalabos = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->fournitures = new ArrayCollection();

}


public function addPrestalabos($presta)
{

    $presta->setCommande($this);
    $this->prestalabos->add($presta);

}

public function removePrestalabos($presta)
{
    $presta->setCommande(null);
    $this->prestalabos->removeElement($presta);
}

public function getPrestalabos(){
    return $this->prestalabos;
}

public function setPrestalabos($prestationsLaboratoires) {
    $this->prestalabos = $prestationsLaboratoires;
}
```

on field "$prestalabos"   oneToMany relation to PrestationsLaboratoire entity on field "$commande"

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ApiResource()
* @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy="exact")
*/
class PrestationsLaboratoire  {

  /**
 * @var id
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
public $id;

/** 
 *@var designation du test : Dosage/Test de stérilité/test endotoxine .....
 *@ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=50) 
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $designation;

/**
 * @var origine du dosage :["OBLIGATOIRE","DP","SUPPLEMENTAIRES","LIBRE"]
 *  - DP(deviation paramétrique)
 *  - OBLIGATOIRE définit dans le rapport de sté
 *  - TRAITEMENT définit dans le rapport de traitement
 *  - SUPPLEMENTAIRES demande complémentaire du client
 *  - LIBRE commande client non liée steriservice
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",length=15)
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 * 
 */
protected  $origine;



/**
 * @var méthode uniquement pour le Dosage  : Simulation ou Extraction
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=45)
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $methode;

/**
 *@var ref du rapport de la methode
 *@ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=45) 
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $rapportValidationMethode;



/**
 * @var ref to sterilisation
 * ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sterilisation",inversedBy="dosages",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected  $sterilisation ;

/**
 * @var ref to traitement
 * ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Traitement",inversedBy="dosages",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 *Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected  $traitement ;


/**
 * @var ref dosages obligatoires rapportSterilisation
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RapportSterilisation",inversedBy="dosages",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected  $rapportSterilisation;


/**
 *  ref dosages obligatoires rapportTraitement
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RapportTraitement",inversedBy="dosages",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected  $rapportTraitement;

/** 
 *@var reference du produit
 *@ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=50) 
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $ref;


/** 
 *@var num des lots concernés
 *@ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=200) 
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 */
protected $numLots;

/** 
 *@var commantaires sur les tests
 *@ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true,length=200) 
 *@Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 *
 */
protected $commentaire;

/**
 *  la commande reliée
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity    \Commande",inversedBy="prestalabos",fetch="EAGER",cascade={"persist"})
 * @Groups({"readCO","writeCO"})
 * 
 */
protected  $commande;
```

My foreign key (commande_id) on PrestationsLaboratoire table  is alway null, i don't understand why? I'm stuck since few hours with this issue. The result on postman is :

```
{
"@context": "/app_dev.php/api/contexts/Commande",
"@id": "/app_dev.php/api/commandes/55",
"@type": "Commande",
"id": 55,
"commanditaire": "bruno.rotrou@free.fr",
"date": "2018-10-15T20:23:45+02:00",
"prestalabos": [
    {
        "@id": "/app_dev.php/api/prestations_laboratoires/16",
        "@type": "PrestationsLaboratoire",
        "id": 16,
        "designation": "test bruno",
        "origine": "supplmentaire",
        "methode": null,
        "rapportValidationMethode": "ref-4588",
        "rapportSterilisation": null,
        "rapportTraitement": null,
        "ref": null,
        "numLots": "125,455,478",
        "commentaire": "les tes sont dans l'aquarium",
        "commande": null
    }
],
"fournitures": [],
"routine": null,
"status": "IS_ORDERED",
"refClient": "ma commande",
"entreprise": "/app_dev.php/api/entreprises/2334"
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have found the mistake.
for doctrine arrayCollection the add methode must de like this without "s" at the method end.

```
public function addPrestalabo($presta)
```

bad was

```
public function addPrestalabos($presta)
```

Note the "s" is in minus.
i don't know how symfony is handling method like addMyProperty ???? i have tried to search explanation but the cause stay open.

Comment: Use Symfony "bin/console make:entity" command. It produces proper getter-setters-adders methods – this will prevent you from typo errors.